# Handling transitions in state machines in python when state values interlap

Tags: python, state, state-machine

I have a large amounts of states where the states correspond to a number in different state machines

```
A_STATE_IDLE = 0
A_STATE_ENGAGE = 1
A_STATE_STOP = 2
A_STATE_STOPPED = 3
B_STATE_IDLE = 0
B_STATE_START = 1
B_STATE_RUNNING = 2
B_STATE_SUCCESS = 3
B_STATE_FAIL = 4
B_STATE_STOP = 5
```

I also have a list over the different transitions of the state machine.

```
"trigger": press_start
"from": A_STATE_IDLE
"to": A_STATE_START

"trigger": press_start
"from": B_STATE_IDLE
"to": B_STATE_START
```

How should i handle the transition of the states and is it possible to do this without putting the states in e.g. a dictionary?

Preferably i would like to handle my transitions in one of these ways.

```
press_start(A_STATE_IDLE) => A_STATE_START

A_STATE_IDLE.press_start() => A_STATE_START
```

When trying to implement this i run into issues with overlapping state values since the python can't differentiate between states since e.g.

```
 A_STATE_STOPPED == B_STATE_SUCCESS
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a dictionary?

Comment: Mostly just due to having an existing template that generates the files containing the states. Changing the existing templates will take extra work and probably cause a lot of unintended issues. If it is not possible without the use of dictionary (or other solutions) i'm still open to those ideas.